# Matlab Unexpected Result/Error? Replacing zeros in array with Inf

Tags: matlab, inf

I'm getting an unexpected result from Matlab and I have no idea why.  My goal is to replace values less than or equal to zero with Inf.

Here is the correct result of what I expect should happen:

```
C = [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1];
C(C<=0)=Inf
C = Inf   Inf   Inf   Inf   Inf     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

But when I begin the process in a different manner, matlab replaces values <=0 with 1 instead of Inf.

```
A = [0     2     4     6     8    10    12    14    16    18    20];
b = 7;
E=A-b>0
E = 0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
E(E<=0)=Inf
E = 1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

Any idea why this is occurring?  I'm guessing it has something to do with logical `E=A-b>0` step, but I don't know why it is different.

My overall goal is to find the index of the closest larger value of a vector to a scalar, and it did just occur to me that I could skip the step that I think is causing the problem and get the desired outcome, like so (with A & b already defined as above):

```
F=A-b
F = -7    -5    -3    -1     1     3     5     7     9    11    13
F(F<=0)=Inf
F = Inf   Inf   Inf   Inf     1     3     5     7     9    11    13
[~,ind]=min(F)
ind = 5
```

BUT, I still don't understand why Matlab was not giving the result I expected above (and I already finished typing the question before I realized the simple solution).  So does anyone know why Matlab gives the unexpected result?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is because `E` is a logical array. Possible values are 1 or 0. If you use `E=double(A-b>0)` you will get the expected results.